# using img element with cover

Tags: css, image, background-image

I want to show images to same ratio.But image sizes get different.Maybe 16:10 or 10:10 aspect ratio.Some images look vertical, some images look horizontal.

I did background cover center with div.But I have to use this to img element.

How can I do that with img ?

```
div.image-content
{
     width: 210px;
     margin: 15px;
     float: left;
     height: 210px;
     overflow: hidden;
     background: no-repeat center center;
     background-size: cover;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only one dimension.
`width:210px` or `height:210px`

if you specify only one dimension, the other one will be proportionately scaled.

Comment: But photo was corrupted